# Publicar dominio de Vercel a dominio propio

Tags: dominio

Tengo un proyecto estatico en `ReactJs` publicado con `Vercel`. Por otro lado pague la reserva de un dominio con mi nombre en Argentina `https://nic.ar/`. Quiero saber como poder vincular, el `DNS` que me brinda `Vercel` con el dominio que reserve desde la pagina mencionada.
Quiero que los usuarios, cuando entren a `www.miDominio.com.ar` se direccione al `DNS` de Vercel `https://miSitio.vercel.app`

***Vercel*** es una plataforma online en el cual permite hacer deploy de apliaciones web:

https://vercel.com/

Comment: me parece que hay algo que te falta.. que es vercel? una vez que compras un dominio, tu pagina tiene que estar en algun servidor web en algun lado... Tenes un servidor web contratado? luego de eso, todos los servidores web te dicen a que ip tenes que conectar tus dns para que anden...

Comment: otra cosa.. una vez que pagaste en nic.ar ya es tuyo.. no reservaste nada.. por lo menos por un año...

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta, explicando en resumen lo que es Vercel.
bueno con respecto a tu aclaracion, Vercel seria mi servidor web o no?

Comment: Donde se compra el dominio, se crean los registros A que dirigen subdominios (**www.**midominio.com.ar, **blog.**midominio.com.ar, **cosas.**midominio.com.ar) a direcciones IP específicas. También permiten crear registros que le delegan la gestión del dominio a otro servidor DNS (el de tu hosting, que entiendo es Vercel). Consulta la documentación de la empresa a la que le compraste el dominio

Comment: una busqueda rapida en la documentacion de esa empresa y listo!!! https://vercel.com/docs/custom-domains

Comment: La documentacion de Vercel la pude seguir, pero me parece que me falta configurar algo en nic.ar
Puede ser que esto tiene algo que ver?

https://help.wnpower.com/hc/es/articles/360016557092--C%C3%B3mo-delegar-mi-dominio-COM-AR-en-Nic-Argentina-

Comment: Por eso. Si no configuras donde compraste el dominio, lo que hagas en Vercel no sirve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Esta pregunta queda respondida con las siguentes documentaciones:

https://help.wnpower.com/hc/es/articles/360016557092--C%C3%B3mo-delegar-mi-dominio-COM-AR-en-Nic-Argentina-

https://vercel.com/docs/custom-domains

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.